# connection abort exception with DefaultHttpClient (httpclient-4.2.6)

Tags: java, odata, apache-httpclient-4.x, olingo

I have following exception

```
org.apache.olingo.client.api.http.HttpClientException: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

Url => https://tp-test.itgr.net:4433/mytest/V4/testCorporate.svc

With Postman tool above URL works fine with get operation but the same URL give above exception with DefaultHttpClient.

```
public DefaultHttpClient create(HttpMethod method, URI uri)
      {
          Logger.logMessage(LogLevel.LEVEL_DEBUG, ODATAstepAdaptor.ODATA_CLIENT_LOG_MODULE, "In side:create(HttpMethod method, URI uri)");
          DefaultHttpClient client=null;
          String[] tlsProtocols=null;
          String[] cipherSuites=null;
          try { 
                String filepath=System.getProperty("com.test.ilt.home");
                Logger.logMessage(LogLevel.LEVEL_DEBUG, ODATAstepAdaptor.ODATA_CLIENT_LOG_MODULE, "FilePath=>"+filepath+"/java/conf/tlsProtocols.dat");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filepath+"/java/conf/tlsProtocols.dat"));
                String str=null;
                ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
                while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
                    lines.add(str);
                }
                in.close();
                tlsProtocols = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
               SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
               sslContext.init(null, null, null);
               //SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext); 
               SSLSocketFactory sf = new CustomizedSSLSocketFactory(sslContext,null,tlsProtocols,cipherSuites);
               sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER); 

               HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); 
               HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1); 
               HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8); 

               SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry(); 
               registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80)); 
               registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
               ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

               client=new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
               client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.username, this.password));
           } catch (Exception e) { 
               Logger.logMessage(LogLevel.LEVEL_ERROR, ODATAstepAdaptor.ODATA_CLIENT_LOG_MODULE,e.getMessage());
           } 
          return client;
      }
```